# PHP - Which form has been submitted from <i> element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am just learning php and the situation is the following.

I have a 2 *.php files. The first one is called **index.php** and it contains the logic. The second php file is called **index.view.php** and it contains html code.

In the **index.view.php** I have a login form and a register form in the same page. Something like facebook.com landing page, where you can login or register a new account.

I have created 2 forms, the first one is the login form:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
    <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method = "POST" class = "form" name = "login">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="userLogin" class = "user" placeholder="Username">  
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" class = "password_btn" placeholder="Your password">
            <i class="submit-btn1" onclick = "login.submit()"></i>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the second one is the register form:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
    <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method = "POST" class = "form" name = "register">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="userRegister" class = "usuario" placeholder="Usuario"> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="passwordRegister1" class = "password_btn" placeholder="Your password">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="passwordRegister2" class = "password_btn" placeholder="Repeat password">
            <i class="submit-btn2" onclick = "register.submit()"></i>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The question is how can I handle this situation to know which form has been submitted. I thought about checking *isset($_POST('userRegister'))* to detect when the user has written data in the register form, and the same technique to check if the login form has been submitted.

Since I am starting to code in php, I don't know if the solution I show could be correct or not. Or if I can use a better solution.

Comment: That would work fine but personally I would post to different scripts to keep things separated and easier to maintain.

Comment: A common solution is to use a submit input/button in both scripts with the same name but a different value.

Comment: As it was mentioned before, you could do that. Also, you could use hidden inputs to name each of your forms. Bu it is always a better idea to separate them!

Comment: You are using `register.submit()` and `login.submit()` so whats the problme to give the ajax call or whatever the submit() does, an additional info about, witch form was send. You can also use a hidden input.

Comment: Give the `name` to the input not the form and check if `isset($_POST["login"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check condition in you index.php like thid:

```
If(isset($_POST['userLogin') AND isset($_POST['passwordLogin']){
// You login code
}Else{
//You register code
}
```